# Don't Abort build job which was triggered by another build job that was triggered manually

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Exclude to Abort/Stop a running build job (example: Job-B) which was triggered by job (example: Job A) where Job A was manually triggered.

I am able to get the details of the job whether started manually or not by using the below code.

```
def was_previous_build_triggered_manually() {
    for (cause in currentBuild?.rawBuild?.getPreviousBuild()?.getCauses()) {
        if (cause.getShortDescription() =~ 'Started by user') {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

So I just need to add some condition here - to check whether the job is triggered by another job which was triggered manually (since I already have the above  code to check whether it is manually triggered or not)

Answer (score 0):

We use a shared library to evaluate causes for a few different conditions. Same as yours, checking if its an automated build vs user invoked (two different causes could mean user invoked).

One function to retrieve the causes into a nice list.

One function to evaluate true/false if relevant causes are present.

Simple if condition to gate.

Our shared library under /vars jobCauses.groovy

```
    /**
     * Checks if job causes contain automated causes
     * Return true if automated cause found
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    boolean hasAutomatedCauses() {

        List automatedCauses = ['UpstreamCause', 'TimerTriggerCause']

        List intersection = []
        intersection = automatedCauses.intersect(getCauses())

        // if no automated causes are found means intersection is empty and then return false
        return !intersection.isEmpty()
    }

    /**
     * Checks if job causes contain Non-automated causes
     * Either
     *** Run by a User
    *** Rebuilt by a User
    *** Replayed by a User
    * Return true if  non automated cause found
    *
    * @return boolean
    */
    boolean hasNonAutomatedCauses() {

        List nonAutomatedCauses = ['UserIdCause', 'ReplayCause']

        List intersection = []
        intersection = nonAutomatedCauses.intersect(getCauses())
        // if no user triggered causes are found means intersection is empty and then return false
        return !intersection.isEmpty()
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves list of causes that generated job execution
     *
     * @return list
     */
    List getCauses() {

        return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().collect { it.getClass().getCanonicalName().tokenize('.').last() }

    }
```

In our Jenkinsfile:

```
Boolean isHumanTriggered = jobCauses.hasNonAutomatedCauses()
if ( isHumanTriggered ) {
    //do the thing
}
```

Comment: Do note that this would require script approvals.